# Card-columns Embed Tweet : Difference Between Chrome and other browsers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I use Boostrap 4 card-columns to share tweet on my website.

I noticed a difference between Chrome and others browsers. In fact, Chrome lost some informations in second and third columns. You can see that in captures.

Could you help me ? Sorry for my english, I'm young french developper. Thank you.

I use this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card" style="border:none;">
   <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
   <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="border:none;">
   <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
   <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="border:none;">
   <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
   <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="border:none;">
   <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
   <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="border:none;">
   <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
   <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="border:none;">
   <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
   <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Chrome Capture**

[image: Chrome Capture]

**Firefox, Safari .. Capture**

[image: Firefox, Safari .. Capture]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code in the question.

Comment: I added my code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**First thing first**: the Twitter `widget.js` should be loaded only once! You could also reference it in the `<head>` of the page. Also, instead of `4.0.0-beta` you should use `4.0.0-beta.2` of Bootstrap.

**About the issue**:
Apparently Twitter renders its widget differently on various browsers. On Firefox and Safari the widget is currently rendered in a standard `<iframe>`, while on Chrome Twitter decided to use an experimental technology called the [`Shadow DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM). In fact, according to canIUse.com at the time of writing this technology is [supported only by Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#search=shadowdom).

While an `<iframe>` completely isolates the css styles of the root document and that of the iframe contents, it seems that this is not completely true for shadow documents.
In this case the internal styling of the Twitter widget interferes with the `column-count` css attribute that gets set with `.card-columns` on the `.card` container. Most probably this is a browser bug and causes issues in other projects (e.g. [spin.js](https://github.com/fgnass/spin.js/issues/252) and [jQuery-mobile](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5508#issuecomment-12760254)) as well.

For sure, Twitters purpose here is to protect the styling of the widgets from the css of the rest of the page. So it should not be you to fix the internal styling of the widget. Having said that, the cleanest solution would be to not to use `.card-columns` as is now.

Two ideas you could do instead:

- As the quickest fix, you could use a simple grid layout made up of `.row` and `.col-4`s. In case all the Twitter cards have the same height this could work perfectly, but leave you with some gaps if the height of the cards vary. Basically this would be:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card" style="border:none;">
                <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card" style="border:none;">
                <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">        
            <div class="card" style="border:none;">
                <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card" style="border:none;">
                <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card" style="border:none;">
                <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card" style="border:none;">
                <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="fr"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Recapping some of the  Tweets from the past week.</p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/942094257472409600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">16 décembre 2017</a></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

- The next option would be to use [`masonry.js`](https://masonry.desandro.com/), which can do the same thing as `.card-columns` tries to do, but it does that with javascript.

Alternatively you could have a look at the script below, which I do not recommend to use in production though as it is quite hackish. It seems that currently the widget’s shadowbox is in `open` mode, thus it is possible to access the contents of the rendered widget and make some alterations to it. So I've come up with the script below to make a quick fix on the internal styles. (Unfortunately I could make the icons of reply and retweet to show up.) Here is the working [Codepen sample](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/mpVeWG).

```
// Wait for `widgets.js` to get loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Twitter get initialised
    twttr.ready(function(twttr) {
        // A widget item finished rendering
        twttr.events.bind('rendered', function(event) {
            // event.target is the <twitterwidget> node
            var widget = event.target,
                shadow;

            // Feature detection, if shadowRoot is in use
            if (!(shadow = widget.shadowRoot)) {
                return;
            }

            // Fixing some styles
            shadow.innerHTML += '<style>.Avatar, .Tweet-body {position: relative;}</style>';
        });
    });
});
```